# Can variables declared in different local scopes be accessed?

Tags: javascript

I've been learning the javascript syntax for about a week now.

How can I move variables from one local scope to another local scope? So for example i've created a for loop off screen that adds an array of values to one main array every round of the loop, the main array is called x. I've not included the loop as it's irrelevant to the issue. In the example below, the purpose for variable y off screen is essentially to take the values contained within the arrays of x to retrieve more data via a web scrape.

Context aside, I can't access the y variable declared inside the if statement. As you can see below i'm trying to use it as an argument in a function called functionName.

```
if (x.length === 1){
    let y = x[0]
} else { 
    let y = x[0][2]
};

functionName(y)
```

Is it better practices to duplicate the function call for every outcome of the if statement like this

```
if (x.length === 1){
    let y = x[0]
    functionName(y)
} else { 
    let y = x[0][2]
    functionName(y)
};
```

Or can different local scopes actually communicate with each other.

It definitely feels less practical to call every function for every outcome of the if statement, especially if it's a larger conditional switch statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keywords `const` and `let` scope is limited to everything within the curly brackets (block) they are declared. If you need to declare a variable within a block yet need to have scope beyond the block, use `var` since they are hoisted. Scope issues are a rarity for me because I have a tendency to declare variables first.

Comment: Okay so does var essentially declare global scope variables regardless of where it's declared?

Comment: If declared outside a function then it's global, otherwise being declared within a function is still local. `var` is relatively safe when declared within a function, it's just a little sloppy if you don't plan your variables very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, now, there are two types of scope: **Block Scope** and **Function Scope**. First there was light, ehm sorry that was another stackexchange site, first there was only function scope.

With the introduction of this new scope also introduced was the different way of declaring a variable, `let`, also `const`, both of which defines a block scoped variable. Before there was only `var` which defined and still defines a function scoped variable.

Block Scope is inside the `if`, `for` and similar blocks which usually enclosed lexically by a pair of curly braces `{}`, not to be confused by the objects, which have same enclosing as well.

Function scope is inside the functions, of all type whether fat arrow or normal ones, hence the name.

So you should either define the `y` with `let`, `const` or `var` once and outside of the `if` blocks you did. Once you the definition outside of the block you can use any of them since block scope is no longer your problem, or alternatively, define it in the first `if` block if you must with `var` so it is still in the scope outside of the `if` block it is defiend in then do use it in your assignment in `else` as `y = something` since it in the scope in there too. Though first way is better.

```
let y;
if (x.length === 1){
    y = x[0]
    functionName(y) // or put call outside the block
} else { 
    y = x[0][2]
    functionName(y) // or put call outside the block
};
// functionName(y); // or put call outside the block here
```

Also note in your first example the `let y` in the `else` block would create a different variable than the one defined in the preceding `if` since `let`, also `const`, defines a new block scoped variable.

Finally, variables cannot be moved from one scope to another or be accessed from outside of the scope they defined in per se, but you can use the scopes to your advantage like defining a variable you need in some of the scopes you have access to, or opposite if you need to enclose it to a scope. It may also be possible to create some custom constructs to share scopes between blocks or functions, I can imagine closures, however this may be a bit out of scope of the post now.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I move variables from one local scope to another local scope?

You can't. That's the point of scopes.

> Is it better practices to duplicate the function call for every outcome of the if statement like this

No. Put the variable in a shared scope.

```
{
    let y;
    if (x.length === 1){
        y = x[0]
    } else { 
        y = x[0][2]
    };

    functionName(y)
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting. So the reason why the value assigned to y within the if statement can be accessed is because the if statement it self is declared in the scope trying to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "move" the scope of a variable dynamically. A variable's scope is completely determined by the block (or function) it's declared in. For two blocks to be able to reference the same variable, that variable must be declared *outside* of both blocks, in an ancestor block:

```
let y;
if (x.length === 1){
    y = x[0]
} else { 
    y = x[0][2]
};

functionName(y)
```

But, in this case, since you want to *conditionally* assign to `y`, you should use the **conditional** operator:

```
const y = x.length === 1
  ? x[0]
  : x[0][2];
functionName(y)
```

Comment: Great, yeah the conditional operator definitely is cleaner.